# More available space than expected using btrfs RAID10?

Tags: ubuntu, raid10, btrfs

I had just created a btrfs RAID10 array in my Ubuntu 14.04 box for the first time by using the command:

```
mkfs.btrfs -d raid10 -m raid10 /dev/sda /dev/sdb /dev/sdc /dev/sdd
```

My 4 hard drives are each 2TB drives. Under RAID10, I had expected to see usable space of about 3.6TB in total. Yet, for some reason, I'm seeing a total usable of 7.3TB (refer to `/dev/sda` below):

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sde1        42G  1.7G   38G   5% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  1.2M  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda        7.3T   13G  7.3T   1% /mnt/tmp
```

Is this unexpected behavior?

Other information:

```
bofh@stronghold:~$ sudo btrfs fi show
Label: none  uuid: a3a65325-0184-46d8-bef7-7ed066c9e320
    Total devices 4 FS bytes used 29.14GiB
    devid    1 size 1.82TiB used 16.03GiB path /dev/sda
    devid    2 size 1.82TiB used 16.01GiB path /dev/sdb
    devid    3 size 1.82TiB used 16.01GiB path /dev/sdc
    devid    4 size 1.82TiB used 16.01GiB path /dev/sdd
```

When I try to list out the RAID type I'm using, I see both "RAID10" and "single"

```
bofh@stronghold:~$ sudo btrfs fi df /mnt/tmp
Data, RAID10: total=52.00GiB, used=48.77GiB
Data, single: total=8.00MiB, used=0.00
System, RAID10: total=16.00MiB, used=16.00KiB
System, single: total=4.00MiB, used=0.00
Metadata, RAID10: total=2.00GiB, used=64.12MiB
Metadata, single: total=8.00MiB, used=0.00
```

Another rather weird thing is that btrfs device scan doesn't throw up any results:

```
bofh@stronghold:~$ sudo btrfs device scan
Scanning for Btrfs filesystems
bofh@stronghold:~$
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 server which I just installed new and ran a dist-upgrade.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm seeing a total usable of 7.3TB

That's correct.

The short answer is that you are seeing the raw space available for putting the mirror copies into, so split it in half to get the 3.6TB you expected.

Calculating disk free space is notoriously confusing with btrfs.  The official btrfs FAQ has a question on [why it is difficult to calculate free space](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Why_is_free_space_so_complicated.3F) in btrfs.

A btrfs filesystem can contain chunks of files with different raid levels.  You can have some files with no mirror copies ("single" or "raid0") and other files that are mirrored ("raid1").

You actually have this in your filesystem right now.

> When I try to list out the RAID type I'm using, I see both "RAID10" and "single"

This is telling you that a small amount of your data in your file system is NOT mirrored ("single").  You need to do a btrfs balance to fix this.  I would recommend doing:

> btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1,profiles=single -mconvert=raid1,profiles=single -sconvert=raid1,profiles=single --force /mnt/tmp

This will convert the single-copy data to mirrored, for both the file data, metadata, and system data (d, m and s).  The "profiles" parameter will make it just affect the data that is currently single-copy.